# How to verify card details in paypal valut Api

Tags: paypal

I have used paypal vault API to store the credit card details.When Iam saving the card I gave wrong card details.So When Iam trying to make the payment It is throwing error.Iam using the sandbox environment

**Is there any process to know whether a card is valid or not while saving the card details?**

Answer (score 0):

Currently PayPal does not validate credit card information that is being stored using the /v1/vault/credit-cards. The card will be validated against the processor when you try to charge the buyer using CARD ID. There is no alternate for validating the card.